# Loop trough image gallery in blog post and display images in separate divs

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I have custom post type with custom blog posts. I have page with list of all post of course. Each post tile has implemented slick slider. And what I need to do is show all images from gallery in post in this slick slider. That's not problem. I did it by this code:

```
<?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
                            foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
                            {
                            ?>
                                <div style="width: 100%;">
                                <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="fancybox"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                ?>
```

problem is when I add second post with different images. Then all two slick sliders has images from two galleries from two different post. How can I tell this difference in this loop?

It is also important that tiles display alternately. First has text on left, slick slider on the right, second has text on right, slick slider on the left, third is same as first, fourth as second. e.t.c. So I have used the above loop twice.

Full code of page:

```
 <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'journal', 'orderby'=>'post_id', 'order'=>'DESC' ) ); ?>
    <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $i=0; ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $i++; ?>
        <div class="post-tile">
        <?php if( $i % 2 ) : ?>
        <div class="row align-items-center"> <!-- tile with text on left, slider on right -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3 class="etap"><?php the_field('etap') ?></h3>
                    <div class="content">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-arrows">
                    <div class="slick-prev-custom slick-arrow" id="slickBuildingPrev">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/img/prev.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slick-next-custom slick-arrow" id="slickBuildingNext">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/img/next.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="building-slick">
                <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
                            foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
                            {
                            ?>
                                <div style="width: 100%;">
                                <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="fancybox"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else : ?> <!-- tile with text on right, slider on left -->
        <div class="row align-items-center flex-column-reverse flex-lg-row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="building-slick">
                <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                            $gallery = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
                            foreach( $gallery['src'] AS $src )
                            {
                            ?>
                                <div style="width: 100%;">
                                <a href="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="fancybox"><img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h3 class="etap"><?php the_field('etap') ?></h3>
                    <div class="content">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-arrows">
                    <div class="slick-prev-custom slick-arrow" id="slickBuildingPrev">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/img/prev.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slick-next-custom slick-arrow" id="slickBuildingNext">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/img/next.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with other topic.
Just replaced my loop with this:

```
<?php
                    if ( get_post_gallery() ) {

                        $gallery        = get_post_gallery( get_the_ID(), false );
                        $galleryIDS     = $gallery['ids'];
                        $pieces         = explode(",", $galleryIDS);

                        foreach ($pieces as $key => $value ) { 

                            $image_medium   = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'medium'); 
                            $image_full     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'full'); 
                        ?>


                        <div>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image_full[0] ?>"/>
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```